# Add icon to an ion-option select

Tags: css, ionic-framework

is it possible to add icon to ion-option in ion-select?

or maybe a css trick?

```
<ion-select interface="popover" >
     <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users; ">  
           <ion-icon name="hand"></ion-icon>
           {{user.name}}     
     </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```